# Opening a link form the phone open the SE app only if it is an SO link

Tags: bug, android-app, hyperlinks

When using the chat from my phone (Chrome) and someone post a link to a question, if the question is on SO, the link is opened in the SE app...

If the link is to a question for example on SO Español, (es.stackoverflow.com), the link is opening directly in the browser, not the app.

All links to an SE site should be opened in the SE app.

Comment: The first one might not be a bug if you have set SE app as the default app (open always in...). You might need to reset the "default app preference" to reset that. The Spanish SO though, is a bug. The URL is not yet registered in the app's supported links.

Comment: Maybe I expressed something wrong, but the problem are all the links that for default doesn't open in the app.